# Running httpclient sendasync in task list, only one task running

Tags: c#, multithreading, dotnet-httpclient

We are downloading a lot of data from a webservice. This is done in discrete calls, with the number of rows in the reply (json) vary from a few thousand to arround half a million. This will take from a couple of seconds to about 90 seconds. We do about 200 calls in one night, some night we do perhaps 500 calls.

After receiving the data I consume the JSON, and bulk insert into SQL Server. This is about 10 times faster than the webrequest.

I've tried to make the webrequests parallel by adding the calls to a task list, and then using Whenany to wait for a task to finish

However when I look at the task list efter WhenAny completes, I have no tasks running.

I have my queries in the list "queries", and I try to add the requests t the task list "Replies"

```
List<Task<HttpResponseMessage>> Replies = new List<Task<HttpResponseMessage>>();
while (queries.Count > 0 || Replies.Count > 0)
{
    while (Replies.Count < 10 && queries.Count > 0)
    {
        string json = queries.First();
        queries.RemoveAt(0);
        HttpRequestMessage rMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "");
        rMessage.Headers.Add("Authorization", Token);
        rMessage.Content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        Replies.Add(client.SendAsync(rMessage, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead));
    }

    var finished = await Task.WhenAny(Replies);
    int succeeded = Replies.Where(a => a.Status == TaskStatus.RanToCompletion).Count();
    int running = Replies.Where(a => a.Status == TaskStatus.Running).Count();
    int waitingact = Replies.Where(a => a.Status == TaskStatus.WaitingForActivation).Count();
    int waitingrun = Replies.Where(a => a.Status == TaskStatus.WaitingToRun).Count();
    Console.WriteLine("Got Reply -   {0} succeeded,{1} running,{2} wact,{3} wrun", succeeded, running, waitingact, waitingrun);
    Replies.Remove(finished);
}
```

I would expect there to be at least one task running after WhenAny completes, but there is just on with status "RanToCompletion", and all the other tasks have the status "WaitingForActivation"

I have tried to loo the list and call "Start" on each task, but that is not possible.

All of this is included in an async task, that is called from Main in a console app, it is run as

```
RunBlock().GetAwaiter().OnCompleted(() => { Console.WriteLine("Done"); });
```

How do I make the tasks run in parallel?

Comment: Also, you can replace all of this with a helper method: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2012/03/05/implementing-a-simple-foreachasync-part-2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would expect there to be at least one task running after WhenAny
>   completes, but there is just on with status "RanToCompletion", and all
>   the other tasks have the status "WaitingForActivation"

You're most likely confusing Delegate Tasks with Promise Tasks.

Delegate tasks (thread pool tasks) are created with statuses either `Created` or `WaitForActivation` and then through `WaitingToRun` they changing their status to `Running`...

Promise tasks (that are generated by async/await) don't have status `Running` instead from `WaitForActivation` they change their status directly to `RanToCompletion`/`Faulted`/`Canceled`.

The Tasks are most likely running they just have different status.

You could find this explained very well in an [amazing article](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/06/a-tour-of-task-part-3-status.html) by [Stephen Cleary](https://stackoverflow.com/users/263693/stephen-cleary).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried sleeping for 10 seconds, and looking at the state of the tasks. No matter how long I wait, a maximum of two tasks will run to completion at a time. As soon as I remove one of them another one completes. Do you why that would be?

Comment: Try changing Replies.Add(client.SendAsync...) to Replies(Task.Run(client.SendAsync...))

Comment: @SørenKongstad 2 sounds like the default HTTP connection limit. Try raising it to int.MaxValue.